# Cobertura 2.0.3 - unable to instrument

Tags: java, cobertura, test-coverage, sap-ariba

I am using Corbetura-2.0.3 with java 1.7 and I am trying to instrument the classes in our build system via command line.  Stuck at instrumenting classes.   Please assist.

Here is the command:

```
./cobertura-instrument.sh 
   --basedir /ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes/ariba.app.approvable.zip 
   --destination /ariba/9r2_sourcing/Instrument 
   -auxClasspath /ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes
```

Wherein,

- `/ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes/ariba.app.approvable.zip` – zip containing classes which I would like to instrument
- `/ariba/9r2_sourcing/Instrument` – Folder to save instrumented classes
- `/ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes` – path where all other reference classes are present.

Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./cobertura-instrument.sh --basedir /ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes/ariba.app.approvable.zip --destination /ariba/9r2_sourcing/Instrument -auxClasspath /ariba/9r2_sourcing/roots-S49r2/install/classes
Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Apr 29, 2014 4:53:27 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler loadCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Loaded information on 0 classes.
Apr 29, 2014 4:53:27 AM net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler saveCoverageData
INFO: Cobertura: Saved information on 0 classes.
```

Also tried with:

- `archivesdepth` parameter as well; it gives the same above error.
- I have updated the `cobertura-instrument.sh` file with the right versions of jars present in Cobertura installed location.

Answer (score 0):

I see , in command you have not mentioned classes which you need to instrument.

*Example*: Below command works.

```
sh cobertura-instrument.sh --basedir `pwd` GenerateReports.class My_lib.class
```

*Note*:

Classes need to be mentioned as complete filename (e.g. mycls.class)

-auxClasspath : Add any classes/jars that cobertura is unable to find during instrumentation i.e. classes to exclude from coverage